# Combining background tasks and commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to run background tasks and commands on my bot, I have attempted to use the `@tasks.loop(seconds='timehere')`
decorator for my background task. My task only works on the github example [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py), but now I am not sure on how to combine commands with my bot.

The task I am trying to run in the background is a function that uses Google API to grab txt from a document and compares it to a previously grabbed txt file to detect changes

```
originalDoc = fetchDoc.fetch(currentDoc)  #fetchDoc - Google API that gets txt 

        with open('referenceDoc.txt', 'r') as f:
            referenceDoc = f.read()

        if (len(compare(referenceDoc, originalDoc))) == 0:  #compare() is a function I wrote that compares strings
            changes = False
            print('no changes\n')
        else:
            changes = True
            for x in compare(referenceDoc, originalDoc):
                # compares the pulled document with the one stored locally
                print(x)

        with open('referenceDoc.txt', 'w') as f:
            # updates the local file with the current original file
            f.write(originalDoc)
```

Please and thanks guys!

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?  Is your task working before you add commands and not afterwards?  Please include all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work?

```py
import asyncio


async def loop():
    num=1
    while True:
        # num+=1
        print(num)
        await asyncio.sleep(.2)


import string
async def no():
    letters=list(string.ascii_letters)
    for i in letters:
        await asyncio.sleep(.08)
        print(i)


functions=asyncio.wait([loop(),no()])
asyncio.run(functions)
```